# How to reference form by name in javascript using an ASP.Net BeginForm Html helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm sure I'm going about this wrong but I'm trying to write a simple javascript method that will set a hidden type value upon a link click.

I'm using the Html.BeginForm() helper that contains two links similar to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Review Only", "Delete", new { id = Model.ReviewId }, new { onclick = "SetDeleteType(1);" })
```

The javascript is this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function SetDeleteType(selectedtype) {
    document.supportform.deleteType.value = selectedtype;
    document.supportform.submit();
}
```

The supportform name obviously doesn't exists since I'm using BeginForm() and can't specify a form name.  Is there a clever way of doing this without calling Forms(0) using jQuery or something or am I completely off???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Controller", "Action", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formId", name="formName" }))
```